# Proper way to debug through installed android app on Device

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to app development, currently i am developing apps in Ionic/Cordova/react-native frameworks, in all these i have pretty much easy browser based debugging options. but when it come to installed apps, i have not found any proper documentation.

so can you please guide me to find the proper way to debug and check installed app on devices, currently not found any relevant information .

Thanks,
Sopo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google chrome ,connect your device to your computer via usb and navigate to this url *chrome://inspect/#devices*  from here you will be able to debug the installed app.

Comment: Hey Alexis_Ni, Thanks for this. but its hangs many time. is there is any smooth running tool is there? but it helped. Thanks